# Strange discrepancy in map pack listings, anyone else seen this?

Tags: google-search, local-seo

If you search for "pharmacies medford or" or "banks medford or", the map pack list that displays does not show reviews or even say "no reviews", even though they have reviews. If you search instead for "computer repair medford or" or most other categories for that matter, the map list that displays shows the stars, says how many reviews or says "no reviews". I am doing the SEO for a pharmacy and would really like to know why some categories reviews are hidden.

Here are pics of what I see.
All listing show their reviews or lack of (without clicking):
http://surewire.net/reviews.png


The Chase listing has reviews, but it is not shown unless you click it

http://surewire.net/noreviews.png

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer. They come from Google reviews. Not everything in this list has reviews.

If you take the company names from the list, cut and paste, and do a search on these company names, you will see to the right the information from the knowledge graph including the reviews.

Reviews are from registered Google users. If someone is logged into Google when they search, they can easily add a review.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I do know that reviews are from Google users. The issue is that in some categories such as pharmacies and banks, they do not show up unless you click each business. In 99% of the lists for other categories, you see the reviews under each business, even if it says "no reviews". I added a screenshot for both searches, or just do the search and you will see for yourself.

Comment: @rerat I did the searches for myself the other night. Each item listed with reviews had Google reviews and the rest did not. This comes from the knowledge graph which will not be regular search data, ie., rich-snippets etc. It comes from trusted sources. I only saw Google reviews. I though perhaps from some of the business review sites, and after some research I did not see any connection with any website. Cheers!!